# Add new parameter for activity in bpsim in SPARX

Tags: enterprise-architect, bpmn, business-process-management

I am using the simulation tool bpsim with SPARX Enterprise Architect. I want to add Added Value parameter to be used in each activity for simulation as I am already doing with ProcessingTime and Cost etc... How can I do to declare a new parameter? how can I use it in each activity? Can I have statistics about this parameter in simulation report?